# how to do dependency injection manually in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm trying to instantiate a class that implements an interface called `RestApp` with a `start()` method.

```
public interface RestApp {
    void start() throws RestAppException;
}
```

The class that implements that interface is the following:

```java
import settings.Settings.Server;

@SpringBootApplication
class SpringRestApp implements RestApp {
    private final Server serverSettings;

    SpringRestApp(Server serverSettings) {
        this.serverSettings = serverSettings;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws RestAppException {
        var app = new SpringApplication(SpringRestApp.class);
        app.setDefaultProperties(Collections.singletonMap("server.port", this.serverSettings.port()));
        app.run();
    }
}
```

It's my first time using spring boot, and i've tried to start the application and it give me the next error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in internal.rest.SpringRestApp required a bean of type 'settings.Settings$Server' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'settings.Settings$Server' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

What I'm really trying to do is decouple spring boot from all the project and the only responsability of spring is listen to HTTP requests and handle that requests with the controllers.

In fact, I'm not using the autoconfiguration of spring boot, I'm using my own class of configuration that uses "Apache Configurations" library, I don't want any annotation in my class Settings.

I've tried using chat gpt but it only says me this crap:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create instances of the needed objects
        Server serverSettings = new Server(); // Suppose that this is your settings class
        RestApp restApp = new SpringRestApp(serverSettings);

        // Do the dependency injection manually    <-- WTF?!?!
        // ...

        // Start the application
        try {
            restApp.start();
        } catch (RestAppException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And i've no found any info in google nor youtube. Sorry for my english but I appreciate your help.

The next class is the class that instantiate the settings records for the database and the server http named: Database and Server respectively. i've tried putting the Component annotation in the Server record but it didn't work.

```java
public class Settings {

    public final Database database;
    public final Server server;

    public Settings() throws ConfigurationException {

        var config = new Configurations().properties(new File(".properties"));

        config.setThrowExceptionOnMissing(true);

        this.database = new Database(
                config.getString("DB_USER"),
                config.getString("DB_PASSWORD", ""),
                config.getString("DB_DRIVER"),
                config.getString("DB_HOST"),
                config.getInt("DB_PORT"),
                config.getString("DB_NAME")
        );

        this.server = new Server(
                config.getInt("SERVER_PORT"),
                config.getString("SERVER_FRAMEWORK")
        );
    }
    public record Database(
            String user,
            String password,
            String driver,
            String host,
            int    port,
            String name
    ) {}

    @Component
    public record Server(
            int port,
            String framework
    ){}
}
```

Comment: You're already using `@SpringBootApplication` which enables all of the annotations. Add an `@Autowired` to your bean and it should "just work".

Comment: can you explain me that? what is a bean? do you mean the serverSettings property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Spring Boot nor Spring Framework without using Beans. So I was looking for another framework/library that have the job done without making any of this "magic" of dependency injection and Spring Beans. And I found this thingy called Jakarta RESTful Web Services that doesn't obligate you to do magic things with the dependency injection and the Beans. So I only added the Jersey framework, that is an implementation of Jakarta RESTful Web Services to my project and deleted Spring Boot. It has an very intuitive API without any magic and is straightforward

Answer (score 0):

> Consider defining a bean of type 'settings.Settings$Server' in your configuration

adding @Component on top of Server class should solve your problem

---

Now that you dont wanna springboot to apply any DI (you wanna practice DI on your own) you should remove all @Component annotations from ur classes. Also remove @SpringBootApplication annotation on RestApp class.
These annotations mark the underlying class as a managed component that spring will take care of creating and injecting dependencies to on your behalf

Answer (score 0):

Add a new method like this so that spring creates a bean with provided name(name not required, you can also use `@Bean`)

```
@Bean(name = "serverSettings")
public Server server() {
    Server serverSettings = new Server(); 
    return serverSettings;
}
```

Or add @Component to the class, name is optional though

```
@Component("beanName")
public class Server {
 //
}
```